# From XY all coordinates find angle

Tags: matlab, geometry

I am new to MATLAB, my problem is I created a triangle, now requirement is to gather all the x,y coordinates on three sides of triangle in order to find the angles to the starting point (0,0).

My approach is

```
side_1=[linspace(0,2,100),linspace(1,1,100)]
side_2=[linspace(2,0,100),linspace(1,5,100)]
side_3=[linspace(0,0,100),linspace(5,1,100)]
all_coordinates=(side_1, side_2, side_3)
```

The 4th line of the above code failed, I need make a matrix that contains all x,y coordinates in order to calculate angles that every points face to (0,0) by atan function. Looking for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three lines of you code created three 1x200 row vectors. I presume you are trying to combine them into a single matrix with dimensions 3x200. In that case use:

```
all_coordiantes=[side_1; side_2; side_3]
```